# Inserting null values with liquibase

Tags: java, mysql, liquibase

We use liquibase to manage one of our MySQL databases' updates, rollbacks, etc.

One small curiosity I've come across is the process of setting values to null in the course of updates or rollbacks. Example:

```
        <rollback>
            <update tableName="boats">
                <column name="engine" value="null" />
                <column name="oars" value="2" />
```

At first I was a bit worried that "null" would literally insert the string "null", but it turns out that liquibase seems to have some smarts that actually inserts a null value.

I was wondering if this was the recommended way of doing this, or whether there is a platform-agnostic way of saying 'nullValue' explicitly within Liquibase?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just omit the `value` attribute on `<column>`:

```
<rollback>
    <update tableName="boats">
        <column name="engine" type="varchar(255)"/>
    </update>
</rollback>
```

Reference: [Update](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/update.html)

Comment: Update still seems to set the field to Null, however, I was not able to find this behavior documented in the reference. The liquibase doc simply says "Note: If it is not set, then the first valueXXX defined is used in the order they appear." (where I assume valueXXX refers to valueNumeric or similar), and never mentions the case where no value is used at all. Is this behavior documented anywhere else? It would be reassuring to know that this is intended, and won't change in the future.

Comment: Update still seems to set the field to Null, however, I was not able to find this behavior documented in the reference. The liquibase doc simply says "Note: If it is not set, then the first valueXXX defined is used in the order they appear." (where I assume valueXXX refers to valueNumeric or similar), and never mentions the case where no value is used at all. Is this behavior documented anywhere else? It would be reassuring to know that this is intended, and won't change in the future.

Comment: would: <column name="engine"/> also set "engine"'s value to null? or do I need the type="varchar(255)" as well?